# Python 2.4.4 incessant type error

Tags: python, typeerror

Im using python 2.4.4 and for some reason it keeps throwing a type error when i try to open a log file for writing... Here is the function in question...

```
import os
def write(inlog, outlog):
  # parse the logs and save them to our own...
  parsed = NTttcpParse(inlog)
  debug("PARSED")
  debug(parsed)
  if os.path.exists(outlog):
    fh = os.open(outlog, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND)
    debug("Opened '%s' for writing (%d)" % (outlog, fh))
  else:
    fh = os.open(outlog, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT)
    debug("Created '%s' for writing (%d)" % (outlog, fh))
  debug("type(fh) = %s" % type(fh))
  os.write(fh, LOGFORMAT % parsed)
  os.close(fh)
```

And here is the maddening error...

```
TypeError: int argument required
```

Please hel... and thanks in advance :P

Comment: On what line does the TypeError occur?

Comment: Why are you using `os.open()`? Do you know that that's only for low-level I/O?

Comment: Please post the full traceback (Should be at least three lines long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes, i made a simple error-- i wasnt entering enough items in the parsed tuple ^_^ Thanks for your answers though!

Answer (score 5):

You are doing file I/O in a strange way.  Here is the way to do it:

```
f = open(outlog, "w")
f.write("some data written to file\n")
f.close()
```

If you want to append, use `open(outlog, "a")` instead.  If you want to read, use `open(outlog, "r")`.  Also read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), which explains basic file I/O operations like this.

Note that in Python 2.5 and up, you can use the `with` statement:

```
with open(outlog, "w") as f:
    f.write("some data written to file\n")
```

(I originally posted this as the main answer before I noticed you said you were using 2.4.)

Comment: +1 correct and concise. It is worth noting that append mode `"a"` also creates outlog if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: (+1)  Aside: in Python 2.5 you'll need `from __future__ import with_statement`.

Comment: Alright! Thanks I'll try it out... but i do the os method because its portable to linux because on my *nix boxes write fails so i have to use os.write but of course i can handle it with simple checks

Comment: LOL that was not the problem at all! I didnt enter enough items in the parsed tuple for the format... >_< srry guys!

Comment: `open` and writing via file objects should work fine on Linux.